# How to programmatically check if a SQL database/server supports compression in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcommand

Building a tool to backup a database that I'm testing locally first. I'm trying to check if compression is supported and change my SQL query based on the value returned. Running it against an actual live server returns 0 or 1, but running the query itself against a local instance doesn't give a value. As a result I don't believe the if statements ever run to change the `CommandText` and my final `WriteLine` test returns the initial compression query instead of one of the backup commands.

I tried changing the if to check for a null, however the else should catch any other values besides '1'

```
string compressionQuery = "SELECT VALUE FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'backup compression default'";
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(compressionQuery, newConn);

SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read()) //while the data reader is checking the records
{
    Interface.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0).ToString()); //print the specified record(row) to the console
    canCompress = reader.GetInt32(0);

    // Backup the database.
    if (canCompress == 1)
    {
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + connBuilder.InitialCatalog + "] "
            + "TO DISK = '" + backupPath + "' "
            + "WITH COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION, NOFORMAT, NOINIT, "
            + "NAME = '" + backupName + "', "
            + "SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10";
        Interface.WriteLine("1");
    }
    else 
    {
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + connBuilder.InitialCatalog + "] "
            + "TO DISK = '" + backupPath + "' "
            + "WITH COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, NOINIT, "
            + "NAME = '" + backupName + "', "
            + "SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10";
        Interface.WriteLine("0");
    }
}

reader.Close(); //stop reading records

Interface.WriteLine(sqlCmd.CommandText.ToString()); //Should print one of the backup queries
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It should return one of the nested backup commands. Right now it simply writes the initial compression query.

Comment: *It should return one of the nested backup commands* - yes - and what does this code do right now??

Comment: @marc_s That was in the first paragraph, I moved it to the bottom. It writes the compression query as if it never stepped into the if statement

Comment: What if the server doesn't support backup compression? No row is returned so the `while` loop never executes. Asides: Do you really want to know if backup compression is _supported_, or _on by default_? `CommandText.ToString()`?

Comment: Well - is there even a row returned from the first query? Does your code ever go into the `while (reader.Read())` loop?? A simple debugging session should tell you quickly...

Comment: @marc_s That's correct, the query doesn't return anything when ran against my local server nor does it step into the while loop. That being the case is there anyway to get that while loop to run or will it only work against a remote server?

Comment: Check [`reader.HasRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows?view=netframework-4.8) before the `while` loop to see if there are any rows returned. Better yet, get rid of the loop since you aren't likely to get more than one row returned, or to cope gracefully if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup compression is not available in all editions of SQL Server. So in my sqlexpress the value is not even in the table, it is probably your case too. `reader.Read()` never reads anything, so you do not get into the if part at all. You can restructuralize you code

```
bool canCompress = false;

using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        canCompress = reader.GetInt32(0) == 1;                                      
    }
}

if (canCompress)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

And you can even simplify the reading like this

```
bool canCompress = (int?)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
```

Comment: Correct running the query against my local instance doesn't give me anything. What would I need to do to get reader.Read() to recognize there isn't a value and still run the loop?

Answer (score 1):

The following code gets a value which indicates whether backup compression is supported and, if so, whether it is enabled by default.

```
using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Your connection string.")
{
    dbConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(
      "select value from sys.configurations where name = 'backup compression default';", dbConnection))
    {
        // The values are:
        //   null  Backup compression is not supported.
        //   0     Backup compression is supported and disabled by default.
        //   1     Backup compression is supported and enabled by default.
        int? backupCompressionDefault = (int?)dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Note that the `value` column in `sys.configurations` is declared as `sql_variant`. The actual type returned can be displayed thusly:

```
select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY( value, 'basetype' )
  from sys.configurations
  where name = 'backup compression default';
```